# Removing a class method in the sub-classes

Tags: oop, inheritance

How can I remove a class method in its subclasses?

For example, class `File` allows lots of methods, including `write()`. I want to have a class `StaticFile` that inherits `File`, but does not provide a `write()` method. Note that, I want `write()` to be unavailable, and not just overridden by noop, or returning error.

Comment: You need to specify which programming language you use, but generally speaking this is impossible, what would you expect to happen when someone tries to access the subclass via a reference to the base class and call the "removed" method?

Comment: I don't have any specific programming language in mind. This in more like a concept question. Is there any other OOP concept (other than inheritance) that allows something like this?

Comment: Your requirement is very confusing, since your "removal" would require to be caught at compile time. I can't think of any programming language that would support that, since it goes against the idea behind declaring such methods to be available on base classes or interfaces. Throwing errors at runtime is about the only solution you'd have

Comment: As I said, the solution doesn't have to be based on Inheritance. It can be a composition or delegation. For example, A has-a B, and defines all methods, except foo(). But this solution requires knowing all the methods, and repeating in A, and implementing as bar() { B.bar() }. I was hoping someone knows a better way.

Comment: You may want to revise the question. The term _subclass_ includes inheritance by definition. If you're open to a solution other than inheritance, that means a solution other than a subclass. It sounds like you may actually want to introduce a new superclass of an existing class.